# Which template is the netbeans default for a new java class?

Tags: java, class, templates, netbeans

Everytime I create a new Java class in the Netbeans IDE, I get this comment at the top of the generated class file (even above the package declaration) by default:

`/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */`

I've been exploring the templates for a while now and I cant seem to work out which template this message belongs to. Shouldn't it appear in plain text somewhere, being a human readable message and all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Tools menu</kbd> → <kbd>templates</kbd> → <kbd>Licenses</kbd> → <kbd>Default License</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Or it might be Tools menu > templates > Java > Java class   I can't remember if it was in the license file, or in the Java class template, since I removed that message long ago :)

Comment: Thanks! It was in the Default License. I had checked all the Java specific templates and did a googling before making my question. I appreciate the quick and CORRECT answer. :-D